# Why does my absolutely positioned table not fill its container div?

Tags: css

I have a table inside a div, and the table won't fill the container div. Why not?

HTML:

```
<div class="fill">
  <table class="table">
    ...
  </table>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.fill {
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}

.table {
  position:absolute !important;
  left:0 !important;
  right:10px !important;
  bottom:0 !important;
  top:39px !important; 
}
```

The table only fills a small portion of the container div. Why?

UPDATE:
Or, If I try the following, it doesn't work in Firefox, but it does in Chrome.

HTML:

```
<div class="fill">
  <div class="wrap">
    <table class="table">
      ...
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.fill {
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}

.wrap {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  top:39px;
  bottom:0;
}

.table {
  position:relative;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}
```

This second version is closer to what I want (since it DOES work in Chrome).

Answer (score 2):

In regards to your original question, this is the answer to your 'why not':

> If the height of the containing block is not specified explicitly
>   (i.e., it depends on content height), and this element is not
>   absolutely positioned, the value computes to 'auto'.

Source: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#the-height-property

Your 'fill' div is set to 100% height, but what is its parent element's height set to? And if its parent element's height is also a percentage, what is its parent's height set to, and so on?

Add borders to your updated example and you could see, the height of 'fill' is 0 as it has no parent with a specified height, and so the height of 'wrap' is also zero. Add a parent wrapper to wrap the whole example with a height of 500px or so and it works as expected in (at least) Firefox and Chrome.

CSS:

```
.fill {
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.wrap {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  top:39px;
  bottom:0;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

.table {
  position:relative;
  height:100%;
    border: 1px solid green;
}
.parent {
    height: 300px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
<div class="fill">
  <div class="wrap">
    <table class="table">
        <tr><td>...</td></tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you keep adding percentage heights to parents, eventually you reach the root element. (i.e. the `html` element in valid HTML). A percentage height on the root element is a percentage of the height of the `initial containing block` which is always the same height as the viewport.

Answer (score 0):

Tables are special, they don't behave like other block elements. Normally, a table will be just wide enough to hold its contents, and no more. Setting a width of 100% for the table should force it to fill the space allotted for it.

Comment: I added ``width="100%"`` to the first version I have above, and the width is fine, but the height doesn't expand.

Comment: That's because of the position: absolute

Answer (score 0):

On .table, put width=100%

You may have to set a width for the td as well.. Depending keeping your layout structured

Answer (score 0):

Your parent div of the table has a width and height of 100% which is going to be whatever the parent element is. The table needs to not be position: absolute, and therefore no need to have top, left, right, bottom set.

```
table {
    border: 1px solid blue;    
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Here's my fiddle of what you wanted, minus the top and right offsetting you have. 
http://jsfiddle.net/jaredwilli/5s4DD/

You can instead use margin to set the top and right but you then cannot use the 100% width, that will not work. You can use display:inline-block, while not having a 100% width but instead dynamically setting the width to be 10px less than the width of the fill div's width using javascript but that's another thing. Same goes for the top positioning. You could do some other things too, but there's a lot of playing with things that you would need to do.

Also, you can use table, no need for a class unless you have multiple tables in the page. 
And remove all of the !important's from your CSS.
It's never necessary to use !important, just saying.

Comment: This looks perfect in Chrome (using the Updated version). The problem is that in Firefox the table height extends beyond (below) the parent div. Chrome seems to have it right. The code seems logical to me, but Firefox does its own thing.

Comment: I am using Chrome 27 and the table extends below the parent div, *as it ought to.* The parent has a static height of 400px, the table is 100% of that, with a 39px top margin, meaning 39px of table should extend beyond the parent (give or take.)

Comment: Yes, that's correct. It's how it should be in Chrome as well. I meant to also say that if you wanted to have the table offset from the right and top as the original code is, `top: 39px and right 10px`, you would then need to set the width and height programmatically with JS by getting the width and height of the parent div and subtracting the 39 and 10 px from that to set the table. but you would also need to do a few other things to make it work as well, most likely that is.